# How to send data to QTableView/QTableWidget (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to send a set of information to `model widget`,  `QTableView/QTableWidget`, Then When user click on a row, can open a new widget with `ID` of  sent by information to `QTableView/QTableWidget`.

1. I use `PyQt`
2. I need to send hidden, it means user can't see my hidden `id` of `database` on `QTableView/QTableWidget`

**Primative Question:** How can send data to `QTableView/QTableWidget` without user can see them in `TableModel widget` such as `id` of my `database table` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide a column in a `QTableWidget` by calling `setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide)` with the column number, and `True` for the `hide` option.

A better solution to this would to be to prevent the user interface from ever receiving this information. A Model-View-Controller setup, or the use of a data access layer could ensure that only the relevant information is sent on to the interface and nothing would require hiding.

Comment: Then given `function` send for each row?

Comment: You should be able to select all of your rows from the database with a single query, but without knowing more about what you're trying to do it's difficult to make any recommendations.